# didInsertElement event and unless block

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying this:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
    this.$('[data-hover="dropdown"]').dropdownHover();
  },
```

And i have anchor with data-hover="dropdown" in {{unless}} block.

But the anchor isnt in DOM at didInsertElement.

Is there any other event for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this. One possibility is to add an observer that watches for changes to the same property as the unless block. When the observer triggers it would add the dropdownHover() code to the afterRender queue.

Far simpler is to make the anchor tag a custom view and customize it's didInsertElement hook. Something like:

```
App.DropDownLink = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'a'
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.$('[data-hover="dropdown"]').dropdownHover();
  }
})
```